# System of linear equation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A basketball club offers two types of memberships.

Membership Y: No registration fee and $\$15$ per hour for court time.

Membership Z: $\$40$ registration fee and $\$5$ per hour for court time.

Which of these relationships is a partial variation, and what is it's initial cost?

Comment: For some reason I can't edit your question.  At any rate, if you want to make a dollar sign you need to type "/$".  Also, this is (algebra-precalculus), not (abstract-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Membership Z is the partial variation. That's because its y-intercept is not at the origin. The initial cost of Membership Z is \$40.

Answer (score 1):

Membership Z is the partial variation because we know that a partial variation is in the form:

$$y=mx+b$$

If we convert

> \$40 registration fee and \$5 per hour for court time.

to an equation, we will get

$y = 40 + 5x$ where $x$ is the time on the court.

To find the initial value, all we have to do is find the y-intercept. We can do this by subbing in $0$ for $x$ e.g. $y = 40 + 5(0) = 40$.Thus, we get the initial amount as $40$.

Just out of interest, you may also want to know what a direct variation is. A direct variation is of the form:

$$ y = mx $$

Thus, the first equation that you had would qualify to be a direct variation because it translates to $y = 15x$.